# XSLT - Initialising a xs:duration parm in call-template

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am trying to add duration recursively depending on a type. I am however stranded on how to initialise the xs:duration parm for the first time. Below is the code I am using. I am seeing an empty sequence error when I run this.

Input:

```
<ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION>
    <duration>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION time="00:00:15.000" hours="0" minutes="00" seconds="15" milliseconds="000"/>
    </duration>
    <type>
        <popupLookups>
            <POPUPLOOKUP translation1="N"/>
        </popupLookups>
    </type>
</ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION>
<ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION>
    <duration>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION time="00:11:01.000" hours="0" minutes="11" seconds="01" milliseconds="000"/>
    </duration>
    <type>
        <popupLookups>
            <POPUPLOOKUP translation1="N"/>
        </popupLookups>
    </type>
</ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION>
<ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION>
    <duration>
        <ESP_TIMEDURATION time="00:00:05.000" hours="0" minutes="00" seconds="05" milliseconds="000"/>
    </duration>
     <type>
        <popupLookups>
            <POPUPLOOKUP translation1="Y"/>
        </popupLookups>
     </type>
</ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION>
```

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template name="sumBrkDur">
        <xsl:param name="iteration" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="brkdur" as="xs:duration" select="PT0H0M0S"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[$iteration]/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/popupLookups/POPUPLOOKUP/@translation1 = 'Y'">
                <xsl:call-template name="sumBrkDur">
                    <xsl:with-param name="iteration" select="$iteration + 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="brkdur" select="xs:duration($brkdur) + xs:duration(following-sibling::*[$iteration]/duration/ESP_TIMEDURATION/@duration)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$brkdur"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your stylesheet sets up a namespace for the schema data types (i.e. `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`) and use e.g. `xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H0M0S')` to construct a `dayTimeDuration`.

You haven't shown any input data and input format so it is hard to tell what you want to achieve with your template and whether you need it. In general, if you want to return/create a certain data type with a template or function then make sure you use `xsl:sequence` and not `xsl:value`, so assuming your template is supposed to return a `dayTimeDuration`, use e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="$brkdur"/>` and not value-of, as with `sequence-of` you return that duration value while with value-of you return a text node (containing the string representation of the duration).